# extjs store collect not working when data fetched through service call

Tags: extjs

I am using ext4. I have to populate four combo box with distinct value using data in store.
But while using collect method on store it gives empty array. It works when I have static data in store but it does not work when I fetch data by using proxy in store.

```
    /* inside view */
    initComponent: function() {
            console.log('inside menu Panel ');
            var me = this;
            var filterCriteriaStore = Ext.create('ITChart.store.StoreForMenu');
            Ext.applyIf(me, {
                defaults:{
                    margin:'20 40 20 20'
                },
                items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'combo',
                            id: 'territory',
                            store: filterCriteriaStore.collect('territory'),
                            displayField: 'territory',
                            valueField:'territory',
                            maxWidth:'100',
                            margin: '20 40 20 0',
                            value: 'ABC'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'combo',
                            id: 'content',
                            store: filterCriteriaStore.collect('content'),
                            displayField: 'content',
                            valueField:'content',
                            maxWidth:'100',
                            value: 'XYZ'
                        }
                        ]

            });
            me.callParent(arguments);
        }

    /* not working */
    /* inside store */
    proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url : 'http://localhost:8080/ServiceName/getFilterCriteriaExt',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'responseDTO'
            }/*,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8; Cache-Control: no-cache'
            }*/
            //actionMethods: 'POST'
        },

    /* working */
    /* inside store */
    data : [
{"content":"XYZ","type":"Song","territory":"ABC","payment":"Paid","errorCode":""},{"content":"Music","type":"Album","territory":"ABC","payment":"Paid","errorCode":""},{"content":"XYZ","type":"Song","territory":"IND","payment":"Paid","errorCode":""},
{"content":"Music","type":"Album","territory":"ABC","payment":"Paid","errorCode":""},
{"content":"Movie","type":"Song","territory":"CHINA","payment":"NotPaid","errorCode":""},
{"content":"Music","type":"Song","territory":"IND","payment":"NotPaid","errorCode":""}
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the store is loaded at that point? Else you'll have to load your store first, because when you define the static data, it doesn't have to actually load.

```
var filterCriteriaStore = Ext.create('ITChart.store.StoreForMenu');
filterCriteriaStore.load();
```

Comment: Hi,
When I used filterCriteriaStore inside the combobox as store then it is working fine and all the values(duplicate) are coming in the combo box but when I use filterCriteriaStore.collect('some column name') then it is not working.

Comment: That's because the combobox will load the store itself, but you're collect('...') function gives a subset of the store, but if it hasn't loaded then it won't work. Have you tried looking what's inside the store when u call the collect function?

Comment: Hi,
I have tried filterCriteriaStore.load() as you have mentioned. And also I have set autoLoad as true for the store.